# React not updating DOM on props update

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux with react and I am facing some strange behaviour.

there is property in redux object `todoList` which store array of object(todo's data)

I am dispatching action to delete todo with updated array

```
this.props.removeTodo(todoList)
 removeTodo : (newTodoes,a) => {
    dispatch({type : REMOVE_TODO,newTodoes})
 }
```

In reducer :

```
 case REMOVE_TODO:{
            return {
                ...state,
                todoList : action.newTodoes,
            }
        }
```

While debugging I found that by redux logger also showing updated state
but my componant is not updating with new data.

for now I am adding new property to the store which is just todo length, then everything works file

But for nested object react not updating DOM.

Any idea about that?

Comment: Where is the state being used in the view?

Comment: @train I am passing it to the functional component

Comment: Please show us all the components and how your using state in them.